# can't install php5-devel on SLES11

Tags: php, yast

I'm runnig for the first time SLES11(SP2) nad I have to install *php5-devel* on it, my problem is that it doesn't work with yast, I've download the rpm file and tried to install it, but it some how impossible to get this fone, because of the deppencies, any idea how this could be done ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For SLES11 SP2, you need the following repositories to install php5-devel

```
SLES11 Base Repo
SLE11-SP1-Pool
SLE11-SP1-Pool-Updates
SLE11-SP1-SDK
SLE11-SP1-SDK-Updates
SLE11-SP2-Pool
SLE11-SP2-Pool-Updates
SLE11-SP2-SDK
SLE11-SP2-SDK-Updates
```

If you upgrade to SLES11 SP3, you need a few less repositories:

No base product, SP1 or SP2 repos needed in this case.

```
SLE11-SP3-Pool
SLE11-SP3-Pool-Updates
SLE11-SP3-SDK
SLE11-SP3-SDK-Updates
```

You most probably don't want php5-devel (which is for php 5.2) but php53-devel (which is for php 5.3)

SLE11 SP 2 has both
SLE11 SP 3 depecates php5-devel and recommends php53-devel